# Looking for an elementary solution to this angle problem

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, triangles

[image]

I came across this when I was trying to prove some properties of a particular parallelogram. It looked pretty trivial at first, but it looks like I've sneezed up the wrong tree with this one.

Comment: This is no known simple method, but there is a method with arctan for calculating this. This is a known theorem. Trying to remember the name of theorem. Something related to navigation. Will paste it here soon.

Comment: Here is the wikipedia link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snellius%E2%80%93Pothenot_problem

Comment: And another one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hansen%27s_problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying the law of sines in the two smaller triangles and eliminating the lengths, you can show that

$$ \frac{\sin(a+b+x)}{\sin x} = \frac{\sin a}{\sin b} $$

From this you get

$$\sin(a+b) \cot x = \frac{\sin a}{\sin b} - \cos(a+b)   $$

so you can solve for $\cot x$ and then for $x$. Is this what you need?

Comment: yup, thanks. guess this goes to show that you can't expect everything in mathematics to have a nice, elegant form